# How to use jolt specification for mongodb date insertion?

Tags: json, mongodb, jolt

I've Mongodb JSON input as following,which I want to transform using JOLT.Can any of you suggest the JOLT specification to get the expected output?

```
Input:{
    "BirthDate": "2020-09-08",
    "name": "duplicate"
}
Expected Output:{
    "BirthDate": {"$date": "2020-09-08"},
    "name": "duplicate"
}
```

Comment: or Expected Output:{
    "BirthDate": ISODate("2020-09-08"),
    "name": "duplicate"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "name": "name",
      "BirthDate": "BirthDate.\\$date"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: OMG!!Thank you very much.You saved the day.

Comment: If we've a large JSON in the input,and if we want to modify only one element in it,say ttltime using jolt spec,do we've to give the entire JSON input in the spec?                              
Example:{"_id": {"$oid": "5b9068de2b31f0439411d3c4"},"ttlTime": {"$date": 1536165487000},"keys": [{"name": "eventId", "value": "0e106756-76f4-11e7-89dd-1067566c6de0"},etc.,]}

Comment: Yeah! If you are going for Shift operation, then you need to write operations for entire JSON in the spec

Comment: No need,I guess.This link expalins https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/561